# Browsers close as soon as opened

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Weird problem in Windows 10 x64. MS Edge and Google Chrome both now open when clicked but close instantly. Internet Explorer and Firefox both work normally. Searched all over for solutions and have tried the following with no success:

- sfc/scannow in safe mode
- deleting Edge package in AppData/Local/Packages then reinstalling with Powershell.
- DISM in Command Prompt (Scanhealth/Restorehealth)
  Can still use the PC, but would be nice to have all 4 browsers working. Any ideas?

Comment: While in Safe Mode did you test to see if the browsers worked?  How about if you log in as a different (new) user?  Have you tried reinstalling Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Techie. I uninstalled and re-installed Chrome but that did not work. I stupidly didn't test the browsers while in safe mode, and I didn't create a new user as it is my neighbour's laptop, not my own. The next time I have access to the machine I'll test the browsers in safe mode and try a new account if my neighbour allows this.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any error messages recorded in the Event Viewer(Windows Logs\Applications)?

Check the symptom in a clean boot environment.

How to perform a clean boot in Windows

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Try to login with another account or create a new account.

Comment: Thanks, Map, for your answer. My reply to @'TECHIE007 covers the new account (there is only 1 user at present), and I'll check the Event Viewer and try a clean boot when I next have access to the machine.